# Anonymous types in java like in c#

Tags: java, c#, anonymous-types

I was studying about anonymous types in c# and wondering if something similar exists in java. Does Java have something like anonymous types in c#?

Comment: Did you even *try* to Google it? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html

Comment: @BartFriederichs: That shows something with the same name, but it has very little to do with anonymous types in C#.

Comment: @JonSkeet agreed, that's why it is a comment, he could at least have shown some research effort.

Comment: @BartFriederichs: But what you've shown is that a Google search that finds that page *doesn't* answer the question. There could easily be something *like* C#'s anonymous types, but with a completely different name in Java.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well there *are* types in Java which are anonymous in that you can't refer to them by name, but they have very little in common with anonymous types in C#. In Java they're anonymous *inner classes*, e.g.

```
Runnable x = new Runnable() {
    private int x = 10;

    @Override public void run() {
        System.out.println(x);
        x++;
    }
};
x.run(); // Prints 10
x.run(); // Prints 11
```

There's no equivalent to C#'s notion of "create a type which has a bunch of read-only properties whose types are inferred from the initialization expression, complete with equality and handy string conversion implementations automatically provided". Anonymous inner classes in Java are *usually* used to implement interfaces and extend abstract classes easily - where you'd usually use a lambda expression in C#.

Comment: @KirkWoll: Well they're types that are anonymous... I'll edit to clarify.

Comment: @KirkWoll: Ah, it wasn't clear to me that you were referring to the *second* occurrence of "anonymous inner class". Yes, fixed.

Comment: whoops, should have been more precise. :)

Answer (score 1):

In Java you have anonymous classes

Comment: But they're nothing like anonymous types in C#.

Comment: I was providing backup cover; I thought you'd gone to bed :-)

Comment: But you start so early!